# get firstChild of div

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get the text of the span element. I have tried two methods using `querySelectorAll` and `getElementByClassName` but both give me the error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'getElementsByTagName'" how do I go about getting the text of the span element?

**javascript**

```
var interstitial; 

// 1st attempt
interstitial = document.querySelectorAll('div.top_bg').getElementsByTagName("span");
// 2nd attempt
interstitial = document.getElementByClassName('top_bg')[0].getElementsByTagName("span");

if (interstitial) {
  console.log(interstitial[0].firstChild.innerHTML);
}
```

**html**

```
<div class="top_bg">
  <span style="font-size:14px;line-height:30px">The text I am trying to get.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You should start using jQuery immediately.

Comment: @SteveWellens that's a good suggestion, but any explanation as to why?

Comment: If you are going to be doing a lot of DOM manipulation, I would recommend a JS framework like jQuery. By including a framework, you get a huge number of enhancements and improvements with minimal code effort. The action you're trying to perform can be done with `$("div.top_bg span").text()` with jQuery, for example.

Comment: thanks but i want javascript only because i am trying to learn  the language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the span in the query

```
interstitial = document.querySelectorAll('div.top_bg span');
```

`document.querySelectorAll('div.top_bg')` returns a collection so you'll have to select a node then apply `getElementsByTagName`

Also its `getElementsByClassName` not `getElementByClassName` notice the `Elements`

http://jsfiddle.net/dRvDt/1/

Comment: "seems"? There are specifications to explain such things. `getElementsByTagName` is a method of both the [Document](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-A6C9094) and [Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-1938918D) interfaces.

Comment: For newbies like me, the fiddle is broken, try this one http://jsfiddle.net/Ha9XZ/1/.  It's the same solution though.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because the object returned by [`querySelectorAll`](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/#queryselectorall) is a [NodeList](http://www.w3.org/TR/2004/REC-DOM-Level-3-Core-20040407/core.html#ID-536297177), and NodeLists don't have a `getElementsByTagName` method. You should do something like:

```
  var node, nodeList, spans

  if (document.querySelectorAll) {
    nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div.top_bg');
    node = nodeList[0];

    if (node) {
      spans = node.getElementsByTagName('span');
    }
  }
```

`spans` is now a NodeList of the spans contained in the first element of the first NodeList, if there was one. The first one will be at `spans[0]`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

if you can use the jquery, you can look for the span html easy:
$("div.top_bg>span").firstChild().html();